# Looping over rows of self-reported job titles to gather publicly available data

Tags: r, function, loops

Suppose I have a data frame with one case of self-reported job titles (this is done in R):

```
x <- data.frame("job.title" = c("psychologist"))
```

I'd like to have this job title entered into a search engine on a website (this part I can do) in order to have data on these jobs pulled into a data frame (this part I can also do).

The following function does this for me:

```
onet.sum <- function(x) {
  obj1 <- as.list(ONETr::keySearch(x)) # enter self-reported job title into ONET's search engine
  job.title <- obj1[["title"]][1] # pull best-matching title
  soc.code <- obj1[["code"]][1] # pull best matching title's SOC code
  obj4 <- as.data.frame(cbind(job.title,soc.code))
  return(obj4)
}
```

However, once I add a second job title in a second row...

```
x <- data.frame("job.title" = c("psychologist", "social worker"))
```

...I get this system error that I'm not sure how to diagnose.

Space required after the Public Identifier
SystemLiteral " or ' expected
SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing

Any advice?

**UPDATE**

So it turns out that there are two solutions that work if I pass job titles that do not contain spaces:

1. **Using lapply()**. Make sure that the job titles do not contain spaces.

So this works:
final_data <- lapply(c("psychologist","socialworker"), onet.sum) %>%
bind_rows

...but this doesn't work:
final_data <- lapply(c("psychologist","social worker"), onet.sum) %>%
bind_rows

2. **Use purrr's map_df() is more flexible**.
   result <- purrr::map_df(gsub('\s', '', x$job.title), onet.sum)

Comment: What exactly are you passing in to the `onet.sum` function? Are you trying to pass the entire data.frame?

Comment: Just the column containing job titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a `lapply` statement -

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(x$job.title, onet.sum))
```

Using `purrr::map_df` might be shorter.

```
result <- purrr::map_df(x$job.title, onet.sum)
```

Comment: Both of these generate the same response/error message:

Find a SOC code below and use with socSearch() function to pull job data.
Space required after the Public Identifier
SystemLiteral " or ' expected
SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing
Error: 1: Space required after the Public Identifier
2: SystemLiteral " or ' expected
3: SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing

Comment: I don't have the credentials for this to check but are you able to run `ONETr::keySearch(x)` at all for any `x` ?

Comment: Yup! I can run this when I have only one job title. However, when I have a data frame with two rows (one job title each), I get the same error.

Comment: What is the code that you use? `onet.sum(x$job.title[1])` works for you?

Comment: Yes – it does work for me. However, when I try to include a second row, the errors are generated.

I'm wondering if I need to have some kind of looping feature...

Comment: So it turns out that one issue is that the keySearch(x) function only works when there are no spaces in the job titles. 

So this works:
final_data <- lapply(c("psychologist","socialworker"), onet.sum) %>% 
  bind_rows

But this doesn't work:
final_data <- lapply(c("psychologist","social worker"), onet.sum) %>% 
  bind_rows

How could I remove the spaces? gsub() should do this, right?

Comment: @ChrisCastille Try this `result <- purrr::map_df(gsub('\\s', '', x$job.title), onet.sum)`

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! Might I have a bit more advice?

How would I write the code onet.sum function to print NA when a given respondent either did not provide a job title or provided one that is not returned by the keySearch(x) function?

Comment: What is the current value that you get when either of these things happen? You may use `if`/`else` condition in `onet.sum` function to check for that value. `if(obj1 == '') return(NA)`.

Comment: That doesn't work because there is a breakdown occurring in an earlier function. Please see updated post.

Comment: I think you should ask this as a new question as this is different from your original question.